# How to properly specify / work with postgres text type in mikro-orm?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, mikro-orm

I have an entity that is storing a serialized json string. I initially had it declared as `string` type but started getting errors when it went over 255 characters. Postgres said it should be declared as a `text` type, so I referenced the [MIKRO-ORM docs](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/custom-types#types-provided-by-mikroorm) and see that they have a a `text: TextType` custom type.

I updated my entitities, and manually changed my db types as the migration wasn't picking up the change, but Typescript wasn't liking the new changes as trying to store a serialized json string into a text type yielded a `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TextType'` error.

I was on a deadline so I just put a `ts-ignore` statement above, but I want to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The docs aren't clear to me and googling hasn't yielded any benefits.

Perhaps someone has insight into this?

```
import { TextType } from '@mikro-orm/core';

@Entity()
export class Event {
  ...

  @Property({ nullable: true })
  meta: TextType;

  ...

  constructor(
    ...
    meta?: TextType,
  ) {
    ...
    this.meta = meta || null;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So how does your entity definition look like?

Comment: Sorry. That was probably important. Added it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two things - the TS property type, which is what your runtime values will be mapped to - and that is still a `string` - and the mapped type that will be used to process the values and define the database column type - which is `TextType`.

The docs page you linked describes the `t` variable, that is a map of all provided mapped types, it just describes what you can use as an alias. All of the following should work the same (note that I also made the property optional on TS level, given you wanna mark is as nullable).

```
@Property({ type: TextType, nullable: true })
meta?: string;
```

```
@Property({ type: t.text, nullable: true })
meta?: string;
```

```
@Property({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
meta?: string;
```

Comment: Spot on. I realized my mistake just now too by looking at the docs more closely. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So a closer look at the docs showed me what I was missing.

```
import { Property, types } from '@mikro-orm/core';

@Property({ type: types.text, nullable: true })
meta?: string;
```

It should still have been a string, but in the decorator, I needed to pass types.text.

Guess this is the issue with deadlines, you miss obvious things.